# How to configure kotlin test output in kotlin gradle DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have let gradle generate a gradle app for me (gradle init --type=kotlin-application).

It users kotlin-test (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test) as test framework.

However, when I invoke "./gradlew build" and a test fails, I get output where the actual failed test assertion is missing, for example

```
de.eekboom.eeksv.SimplestTest > testStreaming FAILED
java.lang.AssertionError at SimplestTest.kt:48
5 tests completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.

> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///D:/dev/eeksv/build> /reports/tests/test/index.html
```

I can of course, open the linked index.html for test results, but that is a bit annoying.

Only when I run that specific test (from within IDEA) I get more helpful output like

```
expected:<3> but was:<2>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:<2>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    ...
    at de.eekboom.eeksv.SimplestTest.testStreaming(SimplestTest.kt:48)
```

When I use Java and the gradle groovy DSL, I can fix this by configuring the `test` task:

```
        testLogging {
            events TestLogEvent.FAILED // Show specific test failures in output
            exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL // Output full failure details
        }
```

How can I do the same for kotlin?

Comment: Does using `tasks.test { testLogging { events(TestLogEvent.FAILED); exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL } }` not work?

Comment: Doh, thanks, somehow I managed to mess this up when I first tried. Works fine now with your exact sample!